# Проверка JavaScript и urllib2

Tags: python

У CloudFlare есть такая штука, называется "I'm Under Atack", которая при входе на защищаемый сайт проверяет, включён ли JavaScript у клиента. Есть ли какой-то модуль для urllib2, который позволил бы обойти эту проверку?

Comment: Для особо тяжелых случаев можно http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/ заюзать

Comment: Эта штука наверняка что-то вроде простого AJAX запроса. Запрос такой навряд ли можно сэмулировать, поэтому остаются безголовые браузеры.

Comment: В дополнение к упомянотому [ghost.py](http://ghost-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ещё можно [`selenium.webdriver` использовать](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)

Comment: https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape - посмотрите как обходят или используйте само решение.